# Google App Engine - DataNucleus JPA - One To Many - Parent/Child - EntityManager.Persist - IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :-1

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

My first post on SO - Hurray!

I am trying to create a Java REST service on Google app engine using their data store. I've got the service up and running & I am able to store single entities just fine but now, I am having trouble storing entities that have relationships. ( IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :-1 - See Stack Trace Below)

I spent some time digging and found several people were able to clear up this issue by re running the data-enhancer(https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/Uc7fVnSqcL0). I have re run the enhancer, I can verify in eclipse that it is running & enhances the classes(presumably no errors). Unfortunately, this has not resolved the issue.

Note: Apparently Jersey doesn't work with ASM 4.0 in production. I had to switch to version 3.1 of ASM and on top of that, I found that JPA 2.0 doesnt work with ASM 3.1 so now I am down to ASM 3.1 & JPA 1.0 - Please tell me I am wrong about all of this.

After some time, I found a VERY basic version of my problem on the internet(with books & chapters) and I am still getting the same error. In my original project, I even tried generating the appropriate child parent keys using the KeyFactory but got the same error: IllegalArgumentException: out of field index :-1

Here is my code, stacktrace and some screenshots of my project workspace. Let me know if there is anything else I can submit to help. Thanks SO!

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

    import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

    @Entity
    public class Book {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Key id;

        private String title;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Chapter> chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();

        public Key getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(Key id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Chapter> getChapters() {
        return chapters;
    }

    public void setChapters(List<Chapter> chapters) {
        this.chapters = chapters;
    }
}


    @Entity
    public class Chapter {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Key id;

        private String title;
        private int numPages;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private transient Book book;

        public Key getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Key id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public int getNumPages() {
            return numPages;
        }

        public void setNumPages(int numPages) {
            this.numPages = numPages;
        }

        public Book getBook() {
            return book;
        }

        public void setBook(Book book) {
            this.book = book;
        }
    }
```

My test REST service:

```
EntityManager _em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

@GET
@Path("/ff")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response ff() {

Book b = new Book();
b.setTitle("JPA 4eva");

Chapter c1 = new Chapter();
c1.setTitle("Intro");
c1.setNumPages(10);

Chapter c2 = new Chapter();
c2.setTitle("Configuration  - aa");
c2.setNumPages(9);

b.getChapters().add(c1);
b.getChapters().add(c2);

_em.getTransaction().begin();
try {
       _em.persist(b);
       _em.getTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    if (_em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            _em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return Response.ok(gson.toJson(b), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

I Uploaded my Stack Trace to:

[image: StackTrace]

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my lib folder:<http://i.stack.imgur.com/YcfmK.png>